# How to properly define a child node for treeviews using VBA Excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I am not sure why there is an invalid key error when I do convert it to a string just like how the examples do it.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Dim i As Long, j As Long, Total_rows_Column As Long
Dim unique_keys As Long

For i = 1 To 5
    TreeView1.Nodes.Add Key:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, i), Text:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, i)
Next i

unique_keys = 0
For i = 1 To 5
    Total_rows_Column = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Col_Letter(i) & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 2 To Total_rows_Column
        unique_keys = unique_keys + 1
        'ERROR IN THE LINE BELOW************
        TreeView1.Nodes.Add Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, i).Value, tvwChild, CStr(unique_keys), Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, i).Value
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: What is `tvwChild`?

Comment: https://www.homeandlearn.org/parent_and_child_nodes.html I just followed this guy's instructions

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the `key` of the treeNode may not contain only digits (trial and error, havn't found any reference). Try something like

```
TreeView1.Nodes.Add Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, i).Value, _
       tvwChild, "Key" & CStr(unique_keys), _
       Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(j, i).Value
```

**Update**: 
The *key* of a node is used as the *name* of the node, and a *name* may not be a number. You can write `TreeView1.Nodes("Key1").Text = "MyTest"` to access the node, but if the name would be `1`, the compiler coudn't tell if you mean the node with *name* 1 or with *index* 1

Answer (score 2):

This is some minimal code, that works, producing this:

[image]

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim i&, j&
    For i = 1 To 5
        Me.TreeView1.Nodes.Add Key:="key" & i, Text:="text" & i
    Next i

    For i = 1 To 5
        For j = 2 To 3
         TreeView1.Nodes.Add "key" & i, tvwChild, "Some More Text" & j & i, "Even More" & j
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```

It seems that the key should contain non-numeric characters and no empty values - [VBA treeview loading issue - invalid key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41505565/vba-treeview-loading-issue-invalid-key).